# Securing the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session, cookies

Unfortunately our application still has to run on HTTP along with HTTPS. I'm trying to secure just the .net session cookie for requests over HTTPS, but it seems to ignore the secure flag.

```
if (response.Cookies.Count > 0) {
    foreach (string cookieName in response.Cookies.AllKeys) {
        if (cookieName == FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName 
            || cookieName.ToLower().Contains("login")
            || cookieName.ToLower().Contains("session")) {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme.ToLower() == "https") {
                log.Info("Setting cookie " + cookieName + " to secure on url " + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
                response.Cookies[cookieName].Secure = true;
            } else {
                log.Info("Not Setting cookie " + cookieName + " to secure as scheme is " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "on url " + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
            }
            response.Cookies[cookieName].HttpOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The code sets the flag fine, but when requested over HTTPS the secure flag is not set.

```
Response sent 64 bytes of Cookie data:
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=5bvrhhf223xp4ahgfruurv4v; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Is there another way of setting this for **just** the session cookie?